# Scale image in React Native

Tags: react-native

Scale image like we do in HTML. `img {height:100%; width:100%}` in react native.

I have tried `resizeMode?: enum('cover', 'contain', 'stretch', 'repeat', 'center')` but none of them work in my case.

```
<View style={{
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    flexDirection:'row'
  }}>
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
        <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          resizeMode="stretch"
          source={{uri: 'http://aristotlebuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Facebook.png'}}
        />
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"red"}}>
           <Text>afdafda</Text>
        </View>

      </View>
```

https://snack.expo.io/ByhjFQo1M

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image)

Answer (score 6):

You have to add the `{height: 50}` to the container for the image...

...and set the image size to `{flex: 1}`

...and spell `stretch` correctly.

So replace:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
  <Image
    style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
    resizeMode="strech"
    source={{uri: 'http://aristotlebuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Facebook.png'}}
   />
```

With:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
  <Image
    style={{flex: 1}}
    resizeMode="stretch"
    source={{uri: 'http://aristotlebuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Facebook.png'}}
   />
</View>
```